# How can I have variable accessible in whole project in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Hi to all I'm beginner in asp.net.

I have Uploader.aspx page.

Whenever called this page execute some code like saving file.

Now I need a varible that count number of uploading the problem is that when I define counter variable, every time that I call the page defined variable again and lost the value.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Depends on the scope in which that value needs to live.  It can be a static value on any class in the code, it can be a session value, it can be an application-level value (similar to session, but at the application level), it can be persisted to some storage outside the application (such as a database or a file), etc.

Comment: you can use application variable , session variable or store this value in configuration file or database

Comment: Explain your projects structure please!

Comment: Use Application variable. Application["count"]=0 ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Application["Counter"] = 0;

}
```

Then you would increment it in your code like this:

```
 Application["Counter"] = ((int)Application["Counter"]) + 1;
```

Note the counter will be reset when the application is restarted, if that's an issue you will need to persist the value in a file or database.